# Facebook Graph API get average amount of users "friends of friends" using fql

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

im trying to calculate the average amount of friends friends

for example if the user has 4 friends :

1. friend A with 5 friends
2. friend B with 10 friends
3. friend C with 15 friends
4. friend D with unknown amount of friends (lets say this information isnt visible to the user)

the result would

- Average amount of friends friends = 10
- Calculated friends = 3
- Total friends = 4;

using PHP and FQL and Graph API for this

problem is that i think the fql batch request i sent is 2 big and i get no response

if some 1 knows a better / working method to do this please help

My code snippet :

```
        //get average of friends friends
        $friends=$facebook->api('/me?fields=friends');
        $friends=$friends['friends'];
        if (isset($friends)){
            //now we have array of friends
            $friends = $friends['data'];
            //prepare the query
            $queries = array();
            foreach ($friends as $friend){
                $friendId = $friend['id'];
                $query1="SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = $friendId";
                $newArray = array('method'=>'GET', 'relative_url'=>'method/fql.query?query='.str_replace(' ','+',$query1));
                $queries[]=$newArray;
            }
            //send batch request
            $batchResponse = $facebook->api('/?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');

            //go over all responses get the amount of friends

            var_dump ($batchResponse); //this is null ... think the request fails beacuse of its size
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to make a batch request for each of the friend of the user, instead you can use the following nested query to do the same,

```
SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```